# error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I have a problem in Laravel as it shows an error. I am using ajax to send request from client to server and backward. This is my AJAX code and I suspected function `append()` is not working.

```
$('#petition-form').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
     formdata.append('content', tinymce.get('content').getContent());
     $.ajax({
         url: $(this).attr('action'),
         data: formdata,
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         method: 'POST'
     }).done(function(response) {
         window.location.href = response.slug;
     }).fail(function(response) {
         $(this).append(parseJSON(response));
         // var getError = $.parseJSON(response);
     });
}):
```

When I try to `console.log(response)` it returns an array.
Could you help me solve that?

Comment: I had the same error. But adding Content-Type: application/json to the request header resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the data  then you can use serialize()

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    ...
})
```

in controller you can get all details like this

```
$data = $request->all();
```

where `$request` is an instance of `Request`

also [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-do-i-post-a-form-in-laravel-5-using-ajax) will help you

I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, I just made the mce my input "proxy" then had a hidden text field with the correct name, then did:

```
function reply(){   
  $("#message").html("Sending.....");
  $("#reply").attr("value",tinymce.get('reply-proxy').getContent());

  $.ajax( {
    url: '{{route("reply_conversation")}}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData( $("#reply_form")[0] ),
```

Perhaps not the cleanest work around, but it did the job  :/